# How to redirect the user to the intended page with the details he want to modify in jsp servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

The main functioning of my project to give privileges to the user to modify the event he want to.
so first page is modify-event.jsp where he will get the list of events present in the system with modify button at the end column

**modify-event.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp" />

<div>

    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>


<%

    HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();

//String id = request.getParameter("userId");
String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "technovision";
String userId = "root";
String password = "root";

try {
Class.forName(driverName);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;


%>
<h2 align="center"><font><strong>Retrieve data from database in jsp</strong></font></h2>
<table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
<tr>

</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#A52A2A">
<td><b>Event name</b></td>
<td><b>Registration Amount</b></td>
<td><b>EventHead name</b></td>
<td><b>EventHead contact</b></td>
<td><b>Event Description</b></td>
<td><b>Action</b></td>
</tr>
<%
try{ 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
statement=connection.createStatement();
String sql ="SELECT * FROM events";

resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);


while(resultSet.next()){
session1.setAttribute("eventid",resultSet.getString(1));  
session1.setAttribute("eventname",resultSet.getString(2));  
session1.setAttribute("registrationamount",resultSet.getString(3)); 
session1.setAttribute("eventheadname",resultSet.getString(4)); 
session1.setAttribute("eventheadcontact",resultSet.getString(5)); 
session1.setAttribute("eventdescription",resultSet.getString(6)); 
//ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
//a.add(resultSet.getString(1));
 //a.add(resultSet.getString(2));
//a.add(resultSet.getString(3));
//a.add(resultSet.getString(4));
//a.add(resultSet.getString(5));
//a.add(resultSet.getString(6));

%>
<tr bgcolor="#DEB887">

<td><%=resultSet.getString("event_name") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("registration_amount") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("eventhead_name") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("eventhead_contact") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("event_description") %></td>
<td><a href="modify-page.jsp">Modify</a></td>

</tr>

<% 
}


} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>



</div>


<%@ include file="includes/footer.jsp" %>
<%@include file="includes/scripts.jsp" %>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when user clicks on any of the modify button he should redirect to the page which will fetch the clicked event details so that he can edit the same, but the case here is its opening the last data from that table above in modify-event.jsp because i made use of httpsession but i guess in the wrong way.
so when user clicks on modify button i redirected him to page name modify-page.jsp

**modify-page.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp" />
<%--<%@ page import="com.event"%>--%>
<style>

    input.eventdescription{
        padding-top : 20px;
  padding-bottom : 100px;
    }


    </style>

   <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%

//    ArrayList[] eventname = new ArrayList[10];
//    ArrayList[] registrationamount = new ArrayList[10];
//    ArrayList[] eventheadname = new ArrayList[10];
//    ArrayList[] eventheadcontact = new ArrayList[10];
//    ArrayList[] eventdescription = new ArrayList[10];
//    ArrayList[] eventid = new ArrayList[10];
//    
//HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
// eventname = (ArrayList[])session1.getAttribute("eventname");
// registrationamount = (ArrayList[])session1.getAttribute("registrationamount");
// eventheadname = (ArrayList[])session1.getAttribute("eventheadname");
// eventheadcontact = (ArrayList[])session1.getAttribute("eventheadcontact");
// eventdescription = (ArrayList[])session1.getAttribute("eventdescription");
// eventid = (ArrayList[])session1.getAttribute("eventid");



%>



    <div class="addevent-content" style="background-color:black">

     <div class="pattern height-resize">
<div class="container">


    <form class="form-horizontal" action="UpdateEvent" method="post"
        id="addevent_form" >


        <!-- Form Name -->

        <center>
                    <h2  id="registerheading">
                        <b style="color: gold">Modify Event</b>
            </h2>
        </center>

        <br>

        <!-- Text input-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" style="color: #fff">Event
                Name<abbr title="Required">*</abbr>
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="event_name" id="form_fname" placeholder="Event Name"
                                               value='${eventname}' class="form-control" type="text" required>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" style="color: #fff">Registration Amount<abbr title="Required">*</abbr>
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="registration_amount" id="form_lname" placeholder="Registration Amount"
                        value='${registrationamount}'  class="form-control" type="text" required>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Text input-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" style="color: #fff">Event Image<abbr
                title="Required">*</abbr></label>
            <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="event_image" placeholder="Event Image" class="form-control"
                    value=''  type="text" required>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" style="color: #fff">EventHead Name<abbr
                title="Required">*</abbr></label>
            <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="eventhead_name" id="password1" placeholder="EventHead Name"
                    value='${eventheadname}'    class="form-control" type="text" required>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" style="color: #fff">EventHead Contact
                <abbr title="Required">*</abbr>
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="eventhead_contact" id="password2" placeholder="(+91)"
                    value='${eventheadcontact}'     class="form-control" type="text" required>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label" style="color: #fff">Event Description<abbr
                title="Required">*</abbr></label>
            <div class="col-md-5 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="event_description" id="email" placeholder=""
                    value='${eventdescription}'  class="form-control eventdescription" type="text" required>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Select Basic -->
                <input name="event_id"class="form-control"
                    value='${eventid}'    type="hidden" >

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-5 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <br>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
        <!-- pattern height resize-->

</div>    



<%@ include file="includes/footer.jsp" %>
<%@include file="includes/scripts.jsp" %>

</body>
</html>
```

So is there any way that when user clicks on modify button and it should retrieve that particular event details in modify-page.jsp from the database for modification and then user can click on submit to update the database .

below is the structure of the database table "Events"

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEcjE.png)

Comment: I would start from the beginning. MVC pattern.

Comment: only 15 days left to submit this final year project. Time is less for me.

Comment: send unique id with url , <a href="modify-page.jsp?id=<%=resultSet.getString("eventid") %>">Modify</a>. Then get id in modify-page request.getParameter("id").

Comment: To learn MVC pattern requires cca half, max. one day, if you are a slow-learner. Google for `jsp servlet mvc pattern tutorial`, there is a lot of results, even some YT videos, if you prefer to watch instead of to read. You will benefit from learning how to do things properly, instead of writing tons of spaghetti code.

Comment: Oh then i think i should give a try can you suggest some links @JozefChocholacek

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt
Suppose i did that what you are saying, but after getting id in modify-page.jsp , how to i retrieve the required other data in the form

Comment: connect db again with [PreparedStatement](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) using SELECT * FROM Events WHERE eventid= ? sql statement.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt
Thanks you saved my day!!!

Comment: you are welcome. I'm happy if you accept my answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send unique id with url ,

```
<a href="modify-page.jsp?id=<%=resultSet.getString("eventid") %>">Modify</a>
```

Then get id in modify-page `request.getParameter("id")`

connect db again with [PreparedStatement](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)

using `SELECT * FROM Events WHERE eventid= ?` sql statement.